# Are sim cards supporting Java Card available, and if so where can I get them?

Tags: java, x12, javacard

Are sim cards supporting Java Card available, and if so where can I get them?

Comment: Have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313992/

Answer (score 2):

Quite vague question... e.g. What you want to do with that smartcard?
I mean, the smartcard from my phone supports javacard and was brought from a common mobile phone store.

If you've got a smart idea about some javacard applet that you want to develop then look at this links: http://developer.gemalto.com/home/faq/simagine-contest.html and http://developer.gemalto.com/nc/download/dev-tools.html. That's simulation.

I think you'll never find smartcards to buy with 3GPP SIM/USIM/ISIM applications and javacard VM on them and necessary parameters/keys to use them in network and for javacard application loading except if you're working in a smartcard manufacturer or mobile operator company.